# How to add 4 or more numbers recursively?

Tags: java, arrays, recursion

I am trying to make a super basic program to practice recursion. So I am currently trying to add 4 numbers together, this is the method I use:

```
  public static void recurr(int[] iarr, int target) {
if (iarr.length==1 ) {
  if (iarr[0]==target)
    System.out.println(iarr[0]);
} else {
  for (int ii =0; ii< iarr.length/2;ii++) {
    int p = iarr[ii] + iarr[iarr.length-ii-1];
    int[] piarr=new int[1];
    piarr[0]=p;
    recurr(piarr,target);
  }
}
```

This method adds two numbers recursively but not the 4 numbers and beyond. So if I give 1,2,3,4 to array , it will add 1 and 2, then will add 3,4 but will not add 3 and 7 which are the results of the addition. How to fix that?

Comment: One way to learn is to try to write out the steps by hand, then implement those steps in code.  This isn't very recursive, and the test for how to end is a little wonky too.  Try to work those out, it'll help you work the whole thing out.

Answer (score 1):

Your method is all over the place, I'm not sure it's salvageable as is.

This is how you generally write a recursive method

### The extremes

Any recursive method needs a mode where it doesn't recurse but instead returns an answer, and generally these modes exist for the trivial situation. For an 'add all numbers in this array' setup, there is a very obvious trivial mode: What is the sum of all numbers in an empty array? 0 of course.

### The recursive operation

Any recursive method that doesn't return due to being stuck in a trivial case needs to describe itself in terms of 'appending'.

The operation will perform recursion, but with parameters that are one step closer to one of the trivial exit cases as described above (a recursive method still needs to end at some point, so you need to progress towards those early-exit corner cases every step or they never will), and then mutate the result of the recursive call to take into account the bit you lopped off.

So, given an array of 5 numbers, the recursive solution would trust recursion to produce the result of summing of 4 of the 5 numbers (that's less data, so that's moving closer to the corner case of a 0-length array), and will then add the 5th number and return that (because we lopped that 5th number off, this invocation needs to integrate it into the result somehow).

### tracking progress

Often (but not always), recursive methods will pass along the complete dataset and not lop off a slice every time; for example, making a full copy of that entire array every loop is a pricey operation. Instead, you can pass along tracking info. In this case, you could pass along the index within the array. The corner case is then no longer 'empty array' but instead 'the index is at the end of the array'. Because the tracking info is often a bit bizarre 'from the outside', the actual recursive method is private, and there is some public method that doesn't have the tracking info that starts the process.

### Putting it together

You're looking at something like:

```
public int sum(int[] in) {
    return sum0(in, 0);
}

private int sum0(int[] in, int idx) {
   // First, the extreme case
   if (idx >= in.length) return 0;

   // Then, the recursion
   return in[idx] + sum0(in, idx + 1);
}
```

Often, recursive methods are not particularly efficient, but they can look clean. The above is extremely simple and clean, in rather sharp contrast to what you've tried to do.

There are many ways to write recursive functions, and as an exercise I suggest you try to write it by passing in ever smaller arrays. You can't just make an array of size 1, you'd have to make an array sized 1 smaller than what you have. You may want to read up on `System.arraycopy`, as you'll need to use that.

But, **always**, when writing recursive functions, break it down into the 3 aspects:

1. Program the trivial corner cases (these do not recurse)
2. Program the recursive call (which must move the input a step closer to the trivial corner case)
3. Program the part where you integrate your slice with what the recursion got you.

Which, for my code above, is:

1. When the index is at the end.
2. Move the index up one.
3. Add the number at 'my' index to the recursive result.

Comment: I wish rzwitserloot just hadn't given you the answer like this, but notice that the first line in his recursive method is how to end.  That's often crucial in a recursive program, knowing when you've finished and you can stop recursing.

Comment: Side notes.  Since the two "sum()" functions have different parameter signatures, there's no need to make their names different.  They could be called just "sum".  I would make the helper function that receives the second index parameter **private** since you wouldn't call that one directly.

Comment: Oh, my bad - I called it sum0 because 'x0' is a somewhat common pattern for naming helper methods, and it should most absolutely be private, I'll edit.

Answer (score 0):

You can do the following, for example:

```
public class MyClass {
    public static int sum(int[] array, int counter) {
        if (array.length -1 == counter) {
            return array[counter];
        } else {
          counter = counter +1;
          return array[counter-1]+sum(array, counter);
        }
    }
    
    public static void main(String args[]) {
     int[] array = new int[4];
     array[0] = 1;
     array[1] = 2;
     array[2] = 3;
     array[3] = 4;
     System.out.println(sum(array,0));
    }
}
```

**Output:** 10.

The idea is to iterate until you are at the last value of the array, in which case you return that element so it can be added to the previous element, etc. The second argument of the method serves as a stopper so you stop iterating at the last element. There are other ways of achieving the same behaviour, but this is one of them, and I think it's an easy one to grasp and reproduce.

Answer (score 0):

```
public static int sumWithRecursion(int... arr) {
    return sumWithRecursion(arr, 0);
}

private static int sumWithRecursion(int[] arr, int i) {
    return arr.length == i ? 0 : arr[i] + sumWithRecursion(arr, i + 1);
}
```

**Output:**

```
System.out.println(sumWithRecursion(1, 2, 3, 4));   // 10
```